# send email to single ExactTarget subscriber without TriggeredSend

Tags: c#, web-services, email, exacttarget

There is an email service [ExactTarget](http://wiki.memberlandingpages.com/API_References) with web service API.

There are [samples](http://exacttargetdeveloper.com/viewtopic.php?id=44) (in php though) for sending email to whole list instantly, or to single subscriber by triggered action.

It's pretty hard to get in it's documentation, and I couldn't find explanation how to send email to a single subscriber instantly without having some triggering actions.

Any help or advice will be great.

Comment: I'm a little late, but why did you need to do it without a TriggeredSend? Using TriggeredSends is how we are able to send e-mails to single subscribers. We have a Triggered Send defined in ET set up to send to All Subscribers. Then use the API to create a TriggeredSend and TriggeredSendDefinition. The TriggeredSendDefinition references the one set up on the ET server using the CustomerKey. Then you just add the single Subscriber to the TriggeredSend object's Subscribers and send it off (using the Create web service method.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only workaround I see is create a list, add single subscriber and send email to that list, than delete list.

In the end it's a subscription service, not a sendmail.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is possible to do with a triggered send.

```
private void SendEmail(string triggeredName, Subscriber subscriber) {
    CreateResult[] results;
    string requestId;
    string status;

    var t = new TriggeredSendDefinition { CustomerKey = triggeredName };
    t.RefreshContent = true;
    t.RefreshContentSpecified = true;
    var s = new TriggeredSend { TriggeredSendDefinition = t, Subscribers = new[] { subscriber } };
    CreateResult[] r = _client.Create(new CreateOptions(), new APIObject[] { s }, out requestId, out status);
    var r2 = (TriggeredSendCreateResult)r[0];
    //add your own try/catch, etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of these help? http://wiki.memberlandingpages.com/API_References/Web_Service_Guide/_Technical_Articles/.NET_Code_Samples